# Multiplying infinite series by variable dependent on summation idex

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am attempting to follow a derivation, and there is a step that I do not understand. The step is written as follows:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty D_{1n}sin(k_nx)cosh(\beta_{1n}t_1)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty D_{2n}sin(k_nx)cosh(\beta_{2n}t_2)=x(\epsilon_2^{ther}-\epsilon_1^{ther}) $$

Multiply both sides by $sin(k_nx)$ and integrating over beam length results in the following equation for the unknown $D_{1n}$:

$$ D_{1n}\frac{l}{2}cosh(\beta_{1n}t_1)-D_{2n}\frac{l}{2}cosh(-\beta_{2n}t_2)=(-1)^{(n+1)}\frac{\epsilon_2^{ther}-\epsilon_1^{ther}}{k_n^2} $$

Note: $k_n=\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2l}\quad for \quad n=\Bbb Z $

I don't understand how you can multiply an infinite series by something that depends on the summation index.

In these equations $x$ is length along a beam, so integrating over the beam length involves replacing $x$ with $l$, i.e. the length of the beam.

I would really appreciate any insight.

Robin

Comment: You should multiply by $\sin(k_m x)$ then integrate

Comment: The multiplication step is the bit I am struggling with. I would appreciate being pointed towards some resources that would help. Or perhaps just being told what this type of operation is called.

Comment: As  you  mention, it's not correct to multiply by $\sin(k_n x)$ since $n$ is being summed over. However, you can multiply by $\sin(k_m x)$ and then integrate. After integration, the only nonzero terms on LHS will be when $n=m$, which allows one to solve for the constants $D_m$. This is sometimes called Fourier's trick, or more generally using the orthogonality of sines.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I thought you had just mistyped $n$ and $m$.